# Find the polynomial $p(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, functional-equations

> **A polynomial $p(x)$ gives a remainder of $1$ when divided by $x^{100}$ and a remainder of $2$ when divided by $(x-2)^3$. Evaluate $p(x)$.**

By the Remainder Theorem, $p(x)$ can be written as $$p(x) =x^{100}\times h(x)+1 = (x-2)^3 \times g(x) +2 $$

for some polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, but how do I solve further?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: The best you can do is to find the remainder when $p(x)$ is divided by $x^{100}(x-2)^3$, and therefore be able to evaluate $p$ at $0$ and $2$. You cannot actually _find_ $p(x)$.

Comment: @Arthur Why is that so?

Comment: Let's say you've found a polynomial $p(x)$ that satisfies your conditions. Then for _any_ polynomial $q(x)$, the polynomial $$p(x) + (x-2)^3x^{100}q(x)$$ will also fulfill your conditions. So, as you can see, there is a _lot_ of room for non-uniqueness. This room ammounts exactly to knowing what the remainder of $p(x)$ is when divided by $(x-2)^3x^{100}$, but nothing else.

Comment: @Henry where did you find this problem? This was on a test today :o

Comment: @Nikunj My teacher gave it to me in a worksheet. Btw, which test did it come in? How do you solve that?

Comment: @Henry Chennai Mathematical Institute Entrance Exam, an exam for pursuing BSc. in maths in India, but I couldn't solve it.

Comment: @Nikunj Hmm, my teacher also said that it was from some exam (I don't remember the name, but it might be that test only).

Comment: This sounds more like a number theory problem as you could set up modular congruences and evaluate using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.